# Laravel 5.1 oembed

Tags: laravel, oembed

Is there any oembed package for laravel 5.1. I have tried [this package](https://github.com/jooorooo/oembed), but I get

```
 BadMethodCallException in ServiceProvider.php line 234:
 Call to undefined method [package]
```

Answer (score 1):

this one works in Laravel 5.2

https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed

add this to composer

```
"embed/embed": "^2.6"
```

then you can do this in a controller

```
//Load any url:
      $info = \Embed\Embed::create('http://www.roadandtrack.com/new-cars/future-cars/news/a29059/volkswagen-golf-gti-heartbeat-concept/');

      //Get content info

      $info->title; //The page title
      $info->description; //The page description
      $info->url; //The canonical url
      $info->type; //The page type (link, video, image, rich)
      $info->tags; //The page keywords (tags)

      $info->images; //List of all images found in the page
      $info->image; //The image choosen as main image
      $info->imageWidth; //The width of the main image
      $info->imageHeight; //The height of the main image

      $info->code; //The code to embed the image, video, etc
      $info->width; //The width of the embed code
      $info->height; //The height of the embed code
      $info->aspectRatio; //The aspect ratio (width/height)

      $info->authorName; //The (video/article/image/whatever) author
      $info->authorUrl; //The author url

      $info->providerName; //The provider name of the page (youtube, twitter, instagram, etc)
      $info->providerUrl; //The provider url
      $info->providerIcons; //All provider icons found in the page
      $info->providerIcon; //The icon choosen as main icon

      $info->publishedDate; //The (video/article/image/whatever) published date
      dd($info);
```